# What does flicking the Wii Wheel downwards or sideways in Mario Kart Wii do?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

In [this video](http://www.mariokart.com/wii/launch/) under "New Features -> Wheel", there are movements to flick the wheel downward and it seems to do some trick (for Donkey Kong on the DK Summit run), and also when flicking sideways

What does flicking it downward do?  I usually do tricks by flicking the wheel upward instead of sideways.  Is there any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I recall, a different animation is played depending on the way you flick the wheel. It has no bearing whatsoever on gameplay, as it's just an animation difference.Think of it as a small exclusive to using the wheel control scheme.